# Keras - CNN Regression + additional input into final fully-connected layers

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Let's say that I am trying to guess AGE from profile pictures.  After performing convolutions/pooling, I would like to add another piece of information such as HEART RATE before making the final prediction.

So instead of 
profile picture --> Convolutions/Pooling  -->  Fully-connected layers --> AGE

I would like:
profile picture --> Convolutions/Pooling  --> Fully-connected layer where new input regarding HEART RATE is added --> AGE

To do so, I created a function as follows:

```
def Add_to_FinalLayers(X, Additional):
    X = concatenate([X, Additional])
    return X

def AgeModel(input_shape):
    X_input = Input(input_shape)
    X = ZeroPadding2D((3,3))(X_input)
    X = Conv2D(32, (7,7) strides=(1,1), name ='conv0')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis =3, name = 'bn0')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='max_pool')(X)
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Add_to_FinalLayers(X, HeartRateData_train)
    X = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='fc')(X)
    model = Model(inputs=[X_input, HeartRate_train], outputs=X,   name='AgeModel')
    return model

ageModel = AgeModel(X_train.shape[1:])
ageModel.compile(optimizer="RMSprop", loss="mse", metrics=["mse"])
ageModel.fit(x=[X_train,HeartRate_train], y=Y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=32)
preds = happyModel.predict(X_test)
```

The sizes of my data are,

```
number of training examples = 600
number of test examples = 150
X_train shape: (600, 64, 64, 3)
Y_train shape: (600, 1)
X_test shape: (150, 64, 64, 3)
Y_test shape: (150, 1)
HeartRate_train shape: (600, 1)
HeartRate_test shape: (150, 1)
```

The error messages I am getting are:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_22 to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (600, 1)
ValueError: The model expects 2 arrays, but only received one array.  Found: array with shape (150, 64, 64, 3)
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.  Expected to see 1 arrays) but in stead got the following list of 2 arrays:...
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: First, you need to define `Heartbeat` as the input to your model by specifying it as `input2 = Input(shape=[1], name='heart_rate')`. Then, you can concatenate it after the flatten layer as `X = Concatenate(name='concat_layer')[X, input_2]`

Comment: Dear Nain, thank you for your kind response.  Following your advice, I added Input2 = Input(shape=[1]) within the definition of the model, and then added X=concatenate(name='concat_layer')[X, Input2] after flattening layer.  But I am getting the same error.  Is it because I am passing only X_train when I am creating an instance of the Model here: ageModel = AgeModel(X_train.shape[1:])? What would be the best way to pass in both X_train and HeartRate_train into ageModel?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work.  When I make predictions, though, I noticed that I need to do `preds = ageModel.predict([X_test, HeartRate_test])`.

Comment: Yeap, you need to send two arrays(image and heart rate) at the test time too because as you defined your model, it accepts two inputs and one output. If your query is resolved, do tell me so that I can put this in the answer section

Comment: Hi Nain, thank you so much.  Yes, I followed your advice and problem has been resolved.  =)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define Heartbeat as the input to your model by specifying it as:

```
input2 = Input(shape=[1], name='heart_rate')
```

Then, you can concatenate it after the flatten layer as:

```
 X = Concatenate(name='concat_layer')[X, input_2]
```

Your model accepts two inputs now, an image and hear beat. Make sure you pass both at the test time to get the predictions.